# Database Disk Usage Almost full

Tags: postgresql

We have our database running on kubernetes cluster on prod env, running some monitoring checks on Grafana using below expression I can see we have more than 86% of disk usage:

cmd:

```
{
      "expr": "1/kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes*kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes{namespace=~\".*\",instance=~\".*\"}",
      "interval": "",
      "legendFormat": "{{namespace}}-{{persistentvolumeclaim}}",
      "refId": "A"
    }
```

In the picture below I can see we have **25GB** of disk usage:

Image 1: [DB disk usage info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4iU3.png)

Then I did an analysis to check witch table contains a lot of data funny enough all our tables disk usage per table is **MB** and some it's **KB** none is having GB disk usage.

Furthermore I did an analysis on our tables indexes size and all of them their size is in **KB**'s each index.

running below scripts I get a table called pg_largeobject which contains **24GB** data but I am not familiar with this table.

script::

```
SELECT *, pg_size_pretty(total_bytes) AS total
    , pg_size_pretty(index_bytes) AS index
    , pg_size_pretty(toast_bytes) AS toast
    , pg_size_pretty(table_bytes) AS table
  FROM (
  SELECT *, total_bytes-index_bytes-coalesce(toast_bytes,0) AS table_bytes FROM (
      SELECT c.oid,nspname AS table_schema, relname AS table_name
              , c.reltuples AS row_estimate
              , pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) AS total_bytes
              , pg_indexes_size(c.oid) AS index_bytes
              , pg_total_relation_size(reltoastrelid) AS toast_bytes
          FROM pg_class c
          LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
          WHERE relkind = 'r'
  ) a
) a;
```

Results::

Image 2:: [large_object_results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKokJ.png)

Can you please assist am trying to figure out what's filling up our database if our tables and indexes only contain **MB** and **KB** data, perhaps someone can help me understand this **large_object** table and how to view contents inside as I got **permissions denied** when trying to select.

We have a script that automatically backs up our data daily am not sure where it rights the backup files when executing below script, can below script accidentally right backup files to our DB. we don't have this issue on other environments as we don't do backup

```
# Dumping the database
  pg_dump -n $DB_SCHEME -C -w -h ${PGHOST_SOURCE} -p ${PGPORT_SOURCE} -d ${PGDATABASE_SOURCE} -U ${PGUSER_SOURCE} --format=c --blobs | gzip -9 > $DUMP_FILE_NAME
```

Comment: Look if the space is consumed somewhere else, for example in `pg_wal`.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe, my background is from a pure backend Java developer never worked on a DB system as a DBA thus am not familiar about `pg_wal` can you please show me an example on how to make use of this tried to google about it not getting clear info. thanks

Comment: You will have to ask your DBA.